# Mac: How do I recursively find the largest files in a subdirectory (ignoring all directories)

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a directory called `root`.  It has deeply nested subdirectories.  In these subdirectories, there are a bunch of files.  I want to find the biggest files in `root`.

I **don't** want to find directories at all.  I don't care about the size of the largest directory, I just want to find the largest files.

```
root
|
- subdir1
  |
  - small file 1
  - large file 1
  - small file 2
  ... lots more files      
- subdir2
  |
  - small file 3
  - large file 2
```

I want to print out `large file 1` and `large file 2`.  I don't want it to print out anything about `root`, `subdir1`, or `subdir2`, even if they're bigger than `large file 1` or `2`.  That's just noise to me.

How do I do that on a mac on the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let `ls` do the sorting->

```
find . -type f -exec ls -S {} + | head -n10
```

Comment: Good, but it doesn't let me see the size of the files.  `-Sl` would be better

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} + | sort -rk 5,5 | head -10
```

Find all files (this ignores directories), then `ls -l` them so I can see their sizes.  Pass that into sort. `-k 5,5` says to sort by the 5th column (the column that has size), and `-r` sorts descending.  `head -10` gives me the largest 10 (not the full list).

Comment: For me this just sorts alphabetically rather than numerically. I had to add `-h` to the sort command to sort by file size numerically